Computing the Jacobian of an image: How to reshape the numpy array properly?
I have a batch x of images of the shape [k, width, height, channel_count]. This batch is transformed by a function f. The result has the same shape and I need to compute the divergence (i.e. trace of the Jacobian) of this transformation. (To emphasize this: The transform is working on a batch; it's the output of a neural network and I cannot change it).
I'm using jax.jacfwd to compute the Jacobian. The output has shape [k, width, height, channel_count, k, width, height, channel_count]. That is the first problem, I actually need the Jacobian per image. So the output should have shape [k, width, height, channel_count, width, height, channel_count] instead. I don't know how I can achieve this using jax.jacfwd, since I don't have a per image transform (only the per batch transform).
And even if I have the desired output, how can I compute the trace (per image)? The output should have shape [k]. I think I need to reshape the jacobian output to [k, width * height * channel_count, width * height * channel_count], but how can I do that?
Remark: Note that I also need to know the value of the transform itself. Since there is no jax.val_and_jacfwd, I'm return the actual value as an auxiliary variable, which should be fine. The solution to my question should still allow this.
EDIT:
Here is a minimal reproducible example:
import jax
import torch

def f(x):
    # s = model.apply(params, x) ### The actual code queries a network model
    # for reproducibility, here is a simple transform:
    s = jax.numpy.empty(x.shape)
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for u in range(x.shape[1]):
            for v in range(x.shape[2]):
                for c in range(x.shape[3]):
                    s = s.at[i, u, v, c].set(x[i, u, v, c] * x[i, u, v, c])
    return [s, s]

jac = jax.jacfwd(f, has_aux = True)

k = 3
width = 2
height = 2
channel_count = 1

x = torch.empty((k, width, height, channel_count))

### The actual loads x from a batch
it = 1
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for u in range(x.shape[1]):
        for v in range(x.shape[2]):
            x[i, u, v, 0] = it
            it += 1

f_jac, f_val = jac(x.numpy())
print(f_jac.shape)

The output is (3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1). This is clearly not what I want. I don't want to "differentiate one image with respect to pixels of another". What I actually want is the "per image" Jacobian. So, the output should be of the shape (3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1) instead.
But let me stress it again: I still need that f takes a batch of images, since invoking model.apply for each image in the batch separately would be terribly slow.
EDIT 2:
BTW, if there is a direct way to compute the divergence of f - without the need of computing the whole Jacobian before - I would definitely prefer that.
EDIT 3:
Regarding only the "per batch Jacobian" thing: Here is an even simpler example:
import jax
import torch

def f(x):
    s = jax.numpy.empty(x.shape)
    s = s.at[0].set(x[0] * x[0])
    s = s.at[1].set(x[1] * x[1])
    s = s.at[2].set(x[2] * x[2])
    return [s, s]

jac = jax.jacfwd(f, has_aux = True)

x = torch.empty(3)
x[0] = 1
x[1] = 2
x[2] = 3

f_jac, f_val = jac(x.numpy())
print(f_jac.shape)
print(f_jac)
print(f_val)

The goal would be that f_jac has shape [3, 1, 1]. (The Jacobian of a one-dimensional function is simply a scalar).

Could you edit your question to add a minimal reproducible example of the code you're running?

@jakevdp I've added it to the question.

I'm getting local variable 's' referenced before assignment. The nested loops just seem to be the equivalent of s = x * x, though, so perhaps we can just use that?

@jakevdp No, sorry, there was a s = jax.numpy.empty(x.shape) missing.

@jakevdp I've added an even simpler example for the per batch Jacobian part (though I'd still also be interested in a more direct computation of the divergence, but probably this is not possible with jax).

It sounds like you want a batch dimension for your jacobian, which you can do by making your f work on a single batch, and then wrapping the jacobian in vmap:
def f(x):
    s = jax.numpy.empty(x.shape)
    for u in range(x.shape[0]):
        for v in range(x.shape[1]):
            for c in range(x.shape[2]):
                    s = s.at[u, v, c].set(x[u, v, c] * x[u, v, c])
    return [s, s]

jac = jax.vmap(jax.jacfwd(f, has_aux = True))

Then the output I get is this:
f_jac, f_val = jac(x.numpy())
print(f_jac.shape) # (3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)
print(f_val.shape) # (3, 2, 2, 1)


Thank you for your answer. I already thought about jax.vmap (but I never used it before), but I think I cannot use it in my application. As I wrote in the question, I really need to pass the whole batch to f, since it will forward the input x to the network model. Querying the network for every single image in the batch instead would be terribly slow.

And please note that this is only answering the first part of the question. I now still need to compute the trace of each of the k (= 3 here) Jacobians. I think we need to reshape them for that say that the shape becomes [k, width * height * channel_count].

If you need to pass the whole batch to f, then it sounds like your computation has dependencies across batches, and so there's no jacobian of the desired shape that will correctly represent your computation.

The network model expects that I pass a whole batch. But the derivatives I'm interested in are separately for each of the images inside the batch returned by the model.

Typically on StackOverflow posting complicated multi-part questions is discouraged because the medium makes it difficult to answer those well. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267059/2937831 The recommendation there would be that I close this question as too broad, but instead I did my best to answer the main piece of your question.

It's actually not a multi-part question. What I'm really interested in is the divergence of f. I only described one way that I currently see, how this divergence could be computed by first computing the Jacobian and then taking the trace.

I'm really not sure what to do at this point, StackOverflow is not a great medium for these kinds of extended discussions with multiple questions

As I already said, I'm not asking multiple questions: The actual question simply is: How do I compute the per image divergence of a batch of images? I only tried to describe what I've already tried and which problems I encountered.

I was answering the question as you put it forward in your example code (the first version you posted, before you edited to add a different scenario). If you have example code demonstrating what you're now calling the "main question", I'd suggest starting a new question thread.

I could not extend the example further, since in order to compute the trace of the Jacobian I would need to know how I can compute it correctly and reshape it afterwards.

Well, now that you know how to do that, maybe you can ask a new question showing what you'd like to compute using that answer? I'm honestly not sure what your main question is, because you haven't included any code showing what you want to compute.

I still don't know it. As I told you, unfortunately, I cannot use your solution since it is crucial for performance to pass the whole batch to the model.

And as I've told you, if your function explicitly operates on batch dimensions, then the jacobian you're asking for does not exist. Depending on what your function does and what value you wish to compute, you could slice-out a subset of the full jacobian, or sum across an axis of the full jacobian to get what you want. Also note that if your function is implemented in JAX, then vmap will generate the efficient batched version for you and my proposed solution should be fine.

Well, with torch.autograd, it wouldn't be a problem to compute what I want. So I don't think it is weird that I've hoped that jax can handle this as well.

I'm certain JAX can handle this without a problem, but I'm not certain I understand your question. You've asserted that you must use an explicit batch dimension in your model for performance reasons. If your model is implemented in JAX, I don't think this is the case, due to how vmap works. But I have no way of understanding whether your assertion is true or not, because I have not seen your code, and without that understanding, I don't see any way to answer your question.
